# XSLT- Break elements from parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My task is to break nested `<ol>` from the ancestor `<ol>` and make every `<ol>` elements in the same level. I have this xml,

```
<main>
  <ol>
    <li>The above</li>
    <li>Tprojects.</li>
    <li>FreeSpan sections.</li>
    <li>The above
        <ol>
            <li>Maximum
                <ol>
                    <li>Middle</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Ultimate</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>The above indicative</li>
    <li>Appropriate Live</li>
    <li>The above Indicative</li>
  </ol>
</main>
```

So, expected output,

```
<main>
    <ol>
        <li>The above</li>
        <li>Tprojects.</li>
        <li>FreeSpan sections.</li>
        <li>The above</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Maximum</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Middle</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Ultimate</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>The above indicative</li>
        <li>Appropriate Live</li>
        <li>The above Indicative</li>
    </ol>
</main>
```

I've tried to implement this using for-each but could not get it done correctly, Here is how I tried this,

```
<xsl:template match="ol[descendant::ol]">
        <xsl:for-each select="li">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ol)]"/>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ol"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can there be further nested levels of `ol` elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Yes, It can go further nested levels.

Comment: And you want to pull them all up to the same level? Or each to its nearest ancestor `ol`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, It should come to the same level. I've updated my sample xml and desired xml accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your both samples, I get the right output with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="ol[descendant::ol]">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::li" group-starting-with="li[. is ../li[1]]">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="li[. is ../li[last()]]">
              <ol>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </ol>              
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="text()/normalize-space()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq79/ and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq79/1

It's XSLT 3 but for an XSLT 2 processor you can of course replace the `xsl:mode` declaration used by an explicit template for the identity transformation.

As Alejandro pointed out, the patterns can be simply expressed as `group-starting-with="li[1]"` and `group-ending-with="li[last()]"`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq79/4

Comment: By the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group) the value of `group-starting-with` attribute is a **pattern**, thus `li[. is ../li[1]]` could be just `li[1]`.

Comment: @Alejandro, you are completely right, seems sometimes I can come up with some unnecessarily complex expression without seeing the easy approach. Thanks for the sanity check, will edit the answer.